# Apache rewrite rule forces download of php pages (CentOS / PHP 7)

Tags: url-rewriting, centos

I did read other messages, but still can't fix this.

I just updated CentOS 6.7 i686 to PHP 7 on my VPS server.

*.html pages display fine in the browser

*.php pages do not display and the browser wants to download the *.php page.

it happens also to pages with no .htaccess in the directory.

Hope some server experts can give me some hints here. Very appreciated!

Update:
I found the error. Somehow during upgrade of PHP 7 this line in httpd.conf was changed:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

I switched it back for each virtual server to

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Then it worked fine after a

```
service httpd restart
```

One word of caution, quite a few older php pages don't work with PHP 7.

Comment: check php installed properly ?

Comment: phpinfo() works only from the command line, I put it into a text file, it's a bit long. Is this line normal:  "Virtual Directory Support => disabled"   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25666483/phpinfo.txt